# php ldap search find attribute

Tags: php, search, attributes, ldap

I have a php application which is querying an LDAP server. Using the LDAP Browser desktop application I can see users listed as:
cn=joebloe,ou=users,ou=people,o=cuid

with attributes like: 'departmentNumber', 'loginDisabled' etc.

Inside my php application, I have this code:

```
$sr = ldap_search($ds, "o=$o", "cn=joebloe,ou=users,ou=people,o=cuid");
```

but that code me wrong and just returns a resource link; it would be nice if I can get the value of the attribute of 'loginDisabled'.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php and http://es2.php.net/manual/es/function.ldap-get-entries.php

```
<?php
// $ds is a valid link identifier for a directory server

// $person is all or part of a person's name, eg "Jo"

$dn = "o=My Company, c=US";
$filter="(|(sn=$person*)(givenname=$person*))";
$justthese = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail");

$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n";
?>
```

Snippet copied from PHP Manual

Comment: Yes, that link has got me started and now I am getting a 'count' of values. Trying to figure out getting the loginDisabled value... thanks

Comment: UpVoted. This is worked for me, I am able to display all attributes but except 'givenName' attribute. Why the 'givenName' attribute is not showing for me? any help please..!

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to get the information on `joebloe`, then you should be searching for him. I think your base DN string is a little too specific.

Try this out:

```
$search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=users,ou=people,o=cuid", "cn=joeblow"); 
$results = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
var_dump($results);

// Print Department Number
echo "Department Number = ".$results[0]['departmentNumber'][0];
```